# Shortcut keys disabled on Chrome menu

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, browser

Why are all the shortcut keys on my main menu in Chrome disabled?

I'm doing extensive debugging, and instead of the convenience of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> for the JavaScript console I always have to go through the menu. The only extension I'm running is the Web Developer extension, but disabling it does nothing for the shortcut key problem.

Comment: @Gareth, please explain how "I am only running the Web Developer extension" *significantly* differs from "The only extension I'm running is the Web Developer extension".  Makes me wonder how you get your points around here.

Comment: the main edit was a spelling correction.

Comment: Yes, thanks, and for that you do deserve the points.  Sorry, I was a bit hasty, but too late to edit my comment.

Comment: it's fine :) There aren't any points anyway for edits, I just do it to try and improve questions/answers. Very minor in this case.

Comment: @ProfKaos, do other hotkeys work in Chrome? For example does Alt-E open the Wrench menu or Alt-D|Ctrl-L focus the Omnibar?

Comment: @Synetech, those keys do work.  It's once the Wrench menu is open, all the shortcuts on it are disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hotkeys obviously won’t work if the menu is open. Once the menu is open, you have to press the corresponding **accelerator key** to access the menu items. If you don’t know the accelerators, open the Wrench menu by pressing Alt+E instead of clicking on it; the accelerators will be underlined (eg for Options, it is ‘O’; for the JavaScript console, it is ‘L’ for the *Tools* submenu, then ‘J’).

The hotkeys you are asking about have no meaning in the menu. How would you focus the Omnibar when the menu has none? How would open the DevTools/JS Console for the menu? How would Ctrl+U makes sense to view the source code of the Wrench menu? Those keys only apply to browser windows/tabs. When you open the menu, you switch from the context of tab, to the context of the menu.

Close the Wrench menu and the hotkeys will work for the currently active tab.

Comment: Wow, I couldn't see the hotkeys for the menu. Normally such hotkeys don't appear disabled in a menu unless they are properly disabled.  Thanks anyway, it's huge help.

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean. The accelerator keys are only underlined if you use the keyboard to open the Wrench menu, not if you used the mouse. As for hotkeys, like I said, they have no meaning in the menu, so they don’t work in the menu, only in browser windows/tabs.

Comment: My issue, now that you answered my original question, is not whether the hoykeys work or not, but that they always appear greyed out.  In a UI that normally indicates that something is disabled.  The hotkeys in the Wrench menu are always greyed out, whatever route I take to open the menu.

Comment: That’s just because the Chromium devs have no designers and/or no experience with UIs. The hotkeys listed are *always* grey and do not reflect whether or not they are disabled. Also note that the actual menu item (ie, the text) is *not* grey, only the corresponding hotkey. Feel free to [submit a bug-report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list) to request that they fall in line with accepted UI standards and user expectations.

Comment: I think you got it on the head with the lack of designers and/or UI smarts, or they just neglected a seldom used menu.  The rest of the UI is quite nice to me.  I am logging a bug report now.

Comment: Oh, and also notice that the items in the Wrench menu are in fact, always **enabled**, even when inapplicable. For example, make sure that no text is selected, then open the Wrench menu. You’ll see that the *Copy* command is enabled and can be clicked even though it means nothing without selected text. Of course it doesn’t work and emits a beep. The same goes for the *Cut* command with selected text in a non-editable area, and so on.

It’s things like this that make me can’t help but think that the Chrome/Chromium team was made up of amateur, novice developers, and this is their first project.

Comment: Insightful answer, I wouldn't have guessed he was keeping the wrench menu open the whole time. However I must disagree regarding the grey hotkey notation. I think the comment "Chromium devs have no designers and/or no experience with UIs" is incredibly harsh. Hotkeys are shortcuts, so it is _assumed_ that you will remember them after leaving the wrench menu. Using hotkeys while the corresponding menu is already open is dumb, imo. Perhaps the "accepted UI standards" are wrong in this case.

Comment: Nope; if that is the case, then the whole menu item should be greyed, not just the hotkey associated with it. “Disabling” only half of an item is confusing at best. I suspect the problem stems from the change they made a couple of years ago when they redid the menu using a non-OS-specific implementation (I recall a few issues with fonts, images, alignment etc.)